# Flexbox - Horizontally Center 3 elements but align on center element

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to use flexbox to center 3 elements together on a page. The middle element is ultimately the center of the page while the left and right elements can vary in width. Please refer to image below.

[image: description of centering]

I don't know if this is possible with flexbox. I'd just like it to be.

No real structural requirements other than I'd like to be able to align the elements vertically on a mobile device or as soon as the window width is too small for them to be aligned horizontally.
[image: mobile view of elements]

Comment: you can create flex-wrappers - and align the color boxes according to your needs (looks like a good solution to me..)

Comment: I'm doubtful that this could be done with a single element. Perhaps three columns though. Basically. if the right element is 'optional' then I'd have to say "No".

Comment: Are there any HTML structure requirements? And what are the values for the non-variable widths?

Comment: The main reason I wouldn't want to have 3 columns is so that I can align the 3 elements vertically when the page width gets too small to have them aligned horizontally.

Comment: @jaunt I edited the description for you.

Comment: @TylerGraf I'd have to think. Is the centre element a fixed width? I assume so.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes it's a fixed width.

Comment: OK...this could be interesting. Lemme think about it....it might be a bit of a struggle but I have an idea that this *could* be done but it might involve multiple wrappers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK...it took some tweaking and possibly involves more wrappers than you might be comfortable with but I think I've gotten close.

**Basic principle**

We need rows, each of which contains three colums for this. Each of those column divs holds a "content" div which recieves the actual content (and thus bg color).

Using `flexbox` we can tell the center column (and it's content div) to be a fixed width while each of the side divs is flexible.

The content divs inside the side columns are auto-width and are aligned as required using `flex-end/start` etc.

When the media query kicks in, the rows become columns instead and the previous 'column' divs become rows in that column.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}



.center {
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 .5em;
}

.center .content {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.left {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.left .content {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: blue;
}

.right .content {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .col {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  
 
  .center {
 margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col left">
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col center">
      <div class="content">Lorem </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col right">
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col left">
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col center">
      <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col right">
      <div class="content">Lorem</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jPXXNv)

There's still some work to do depending on the break-point you want and exacly how the 'mobile' sized design is supposed to look...but I think I've made a fairly good start.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!